# Editing or removing a published third party library would effect the app?

Tags: android, gradle

I am worried if my application would not work if the source of code the third party library that installed with gradle dependency is changed or removed. For example: `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'` would it still work if retrofit organization stop working or change something in source code?

Comment: If the *source* code is removed? It depends on the given package, but almost all dependencies are distrbutions and not built from source. If you *update* a dependency version, and there's a breaking change, of course your code won't work--that's how programming works; when contracts change, code can break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first things it depends on central repository in case of jcenter or google repo : the answer to your question is **NO** , you don't have to worry about that because:

1. when the library is on public the owner can not remove it
2. if the owner change the source code so he or she has to change the library version and the older version will not be removed